# How do I get an Android device's location without using LocationClient?

Tags: android, android-location

I have been trying to make a simple app that displays the user's longitude and latitude, but I have been unable to determine how to do this without using any classes that have recently been deprecated (such as [LocationClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html)).

The Google Play services documentation says to use [LocationServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices.html), but the code examples on the Android website still use the deprecated classes, and I have been unable to find any examples using the non-deprecated classes on other websites.  As such, I have been wondering if anyone had any code examples that return the users location using the classes and interfaces in Google Play Services' Location Services, because I have been unable to determine how.

**Edit**: Just to clarify, I want to use the fused location provider APIs because it seems that everything I have read says they are more battery efficient than the location APIs provided by the Android framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) using service, this guy really have nice tutorials.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);//or GPS provider
double lat=location.getLatitude();
double lng=location.getLongitude();
```